# Mounted Android System.img unable to edit

Tags: mount, android, mountpoint, hacking

I have mounted an android system image using the command:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop system.img sys/
```

When I go into the mount point, all of the files are easy to open. I can go through just about everything. The problem comes when I try to edit the files. I cannot save anything. It says that there is not space left on the device. I have plenty of space left on the device itself, so that means that the mount point is out of space.

No big deal, right? Wrong. I tried deleting some files that were much bigger than the one I was trying to overwrite, but the same problem happened. In fact, the total disk size actually shrunk by the amount I had removed, once again leaving me at 0 free space.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If the img file in your /etc/fstab? If it is it may be listed as being mounted in a read-only state (ro). You can either edit fstab to change ro to rw or you can explicitly state to mount the img file as read-write from the commandline by adding `rw` option after `-o` in your mount command.

`sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop,rw system.img sys/`

If you are still short on free space you may need to resize the image file. This can be done with GUI GParted via `sudo gparted /dev/loop0` then use menus to make the file larger so you have some free space to work with.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer]
This was apparently a bug in Ubuntu. The way that I got around it was by using the `resize2fs` command to make the partition file bigger. The exact command I ran was `sudo resize2fs system.img 520M` 
**NOTE:** You may have to run `sudo resize2fs system.img 1000M` first and then reduce the size back to `520M` by using the command above.